# Why is gid_t not in my sys/types header file?

Tags: c, windows, systypes.h

I am trying to run this program in C with Dev C++ in Windows 10:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main()
{
    printf("gid_t: %zu\n", sizeof(gid_t));
}
```

And this error shows:
[Error] 'gid_t' was not declared in this scope.

I checked that gid_t is suppose to be with in the sys/types.h file but when I opened the file it is not there. How can I make this work?

Comment: Probably because `gid_t` is not part of the C standard

Comment: Isn't a `gid` (group ID, I believe?) a unix specific thing, hence absent on Windows?

Comment: `gid_t` is refers to a group ID on UNIX-like systems.  Why do you need to use this type on Windows?

Comment: Oh ok that made alot of scene. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use **Windows**, but do:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
```

That is not going to work, since that header is part of UNIX (not Windows).

`gid_t` is not part of Standard C. As a result, it can be found only in platform specific implementations (i.e. UNIX in that case).

---

An ugly workaround, is to typedef-it yourself, like this:

```
typedef int gid_t;
```

except if you really know what you are doing, and `gid_t` might be a different type in your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

This would be because Windows is not Unix. `sys/types.h` is part of the Unix/POSIX API.

Comment: Hmm. Is WNU a thing?